# Array.prototype.sort() con guion bajo

Tags: javascript, json, array, reactjs

```
.json => 
{
"secuencia":7,
"subSecuencia":0,
"codigo":"7_0",
"descripcion":"7/0",
"direccion":"Bill Gate 123",
"localidad":"Algún Lugar"
},


fn => 
ordenarSecuencia() {    
        return function (a,b) {
            var aLocalidad = a.localidad.toUpperCase();
            var bLocalidad = b.localidad.toUpperCase();;
            var aDescripcion = a.descripcion.toUpperCase();;
            var bDescripcion = b.descripcion.toUpperCase();;
    
            if(aLocalidad === bLocalidad)
        {
                if (!isNaN(a.direccion))
                    aDescripcion = Number(a.descripcion);
                if (!isNaN(b.descripcion))
                    bDescripcion = Number(b.descripcion);
                return (aDescripcion < bDescripcion) ? -1 : (aDescripcion > bDescripcion) ? 1 : 0;
        }
            else
        {
                return (aLocalidad < bLocalidad) ? -1 : 1;
        }        
    }
}
```

Tengo varias objetos json con ese formato y en descripción los números son secuenciales, a saber: 11_0/ 12_0/...20_0/21_0/22_0.../30_0/31_0...etc y cuando hago el llamado, descripción no sigue el orden correcto ya que el número 7_0 aparece al final cuando debería estar al principio. De qué manera podría solucionar este comportamiento?
Gracias por cualquier aporte!
Saludos

Comment: En el primer `if` la función `isNaN()` evalua `a.direccion`. ¿No debería ser `a.descripcion` al igual que `b.descripcion`? Adicionalmente creo que deberías hacer un split respecto a la `/` y evaluar solo el número que no es cero, claro, asumiendo que el número después de la diagonal siempre es cero y/o que no te importa su valor.

Comment: Hola! Sí es un error que quedo de las pruebas que iba haciendo! Muchas gracias por corregirlo y hacerme aprender.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que [isNan](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN) devuelve verdadero cuando la cadena no puede ser interpretada como número y, ten por seguro que `7_0` o `7/0` o `Bill Gate 123` siempre van a devolver verdadero, por lo nunca entra en `if(!isNaN(a.direccion))`.

Además, en la pregunta mencionas que la descripción contiene números separados por guiones, pero en el elemento de muestra está separado por diagonal. En caso de ser necesario, adapta este ejemplo para modificar propiedad y separador a usar:

```js
let json = [
  {
    "secuencia":15,
    "subSecuencia":0,
    "codigo":"15_0",
    "descripcion":"15/0",
    "direccion":"Bill Gate 123",
    "localidad":"Algún Lugar"
  },
  {
    "secuencia":3,
    "subSecuencia":0,
    "codigo":"3_0",
    "descripcion":"3/0",
    "direccion":"Bill Gate 123",
    "localidad":"Algún Lugar"
  },
  {
    "secuencia":7,
    "subSecuencia":0,
    "codigo":"7_0",
    "descripcion":"7/0",
    "direccion":"Bill Gate 123",
    "localidad":"Algún Lugar"
  }
];


function ordenarSecuencia(a, b) {    
    let aLocalidad = a.localidad.toUpperCase();
    let bLocalidad = b.localidad.toUpperCase();;
    let aDescripcion = a.descripcion.toUpperCase();;
    let bDescripcion = b.descripcion.toUpperCase();;
    
    if(aLocalidad === bLocalidad) {
        // Separar descripción (¿o código?) por diagonal (¿o guión?)
        let aParts = a.descripcion.split('/');
        let bParts = b.descripcion.split('/');
        // Solo si cada arreglo contiene dos elementos
        if(aParts.length == 2 && bParts.length == 2) {
            // Tratar de convertir en entero
            let aDir = parseInt(aParts[0]);
            let bDir = parseInt(bParts[0]);
            // Solo si ambos son enteros
            if(aDir && bDir) {
                return aDir - bDir;
            }
        }
        return (aDescripcion < bDescripcion) ? -1 : (aDescripcion > bDescripcion) ? 1 : 0;
    } else {
        return (aLocalidad < bLocalidad) ? -1 : 1;
    }        
}
console.log(json.sort(ordenarSecuencia));
```

**Importante:** Solo se está tomando en cuenta el número antes del separador, en caso de que el segundo número no sea cero y se pueda repetir el primero, probablemente (¿seguramente?) no funcione como esperas.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda! Estoy usando el split y todo va perfecto.